# Sword and up arrow symbol

Tags: dark-souls-2

A sword with an up arrow symbol is present under my stamina bar but I have no clue of what it's about. My guess is that I may have a better weapon in my inventory than the one equipped. What is that symbol for?

Comment: Remembering the way Dark Souls did it, my guess would be that you have some beneficial enchantment (from armor, a ring, or the weapon itself) raising your physical attack.

Comment: It may be, I have a sword with inflicts flames damage too. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a positive buff, probably it's from the ring dropped by the pursuer which increased physical attack.